# I can't mount partitions via /etc/fstab, the error appears

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab

I've tried to mount my new partitions by editing /etc/fstab, but error appears.
When I try to do it by *mount* command, all works fine and I can mount them.
What's wrong?

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-XVpMjvfuIwUMG9eeZN2E09sODMkxF3I8j6u3WkZegGllXAx08ZPZROjo66HKfnG8 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2d747eec-1c31-4c12-849c-efe362e3245e /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
UUID=a6c59d0e-37a7-4532-b843-6025dabef69f /mnt/sdb1 ext4 default 0 2
UUID=b12d193a-6d04-4cbb-a8da-d8405b38dae0 /mnt/sdb2 btrfs default 0 2
UUID=55165d2b-f3b5-46b2-af04-7366861c82b6 /mnt/sdb3 xfs default 0 2
UUID=1B74-0C7D /mnt/sdb4 vfat default 0 2


user@ubuntu2:~$ sudo mount -a

mount: /mnt/sdb1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /mnt/sdb2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /mnt/sdb3: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /mnt/sdb4: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

user@ubuntu2:~$ sudo lsblk -f
  sdb
├─sdb1                    ext4               a6c59d0e-37a7-4532-b843-6025dabef69f
├─sdb2                    btrfs              b12d193a-6d04-4cbb-a8da-d8405b38dae0
├─sdb3                    xfs                55165d2b-f3b5-46b2-af04-7366861c82b6
└─sdb4                    vfat               1B74-0C7D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in the options, it's `defaults` for the default set of mount options, not `default`. There's no such option `default` so mount fails because of that.

Note, if you see similar error from mount in the future, you should always check the log, kernel will print additional information, in this case you should see something like:

> xfs: Unknown parameter 'default'